# UserForm Textbox Slow and Not Showing Characters as Typed

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I'm attempting to get a listbox in a userform to dynamically filter content by what is typed into a textbox on that same form.  It works, but when the user starts typing it basically freezes up while executing the code to filter.  If I type a series of characters fast the textbox will not show the characters for a few seconds.  I'd like to dynamically filter the listbox without the lag.

I've attempted to create a timer that times how long it has been since the user last typed a character before executing the filter, but that brought along with it another set of problems including the last character a user types not firing the `textbox_change` if it was typed fast in relation to the penultimate character.

```
Private Sub FilterTextBox_Change()

Dim bSelected As Boolean
Dim lListIncrementer As Long
Dim lDictionaryIncrementer As Long
Dim lOriginalListBoxDictionaryIncrementer As Long
Dim lLastListItem As Long
Dim sFilterString As String
Dim lDictionaryIncrementerOffset As Long
Dim dTimerDifference As Double
Dim sCurrentString As String

sFilterString = UCase(InvoiceProductAssociation.FilterTextBox.Text)
lLastListItem = InvoiceProductAssociation.CatapultItemIdAndDescriptionListBox.ListCount - 1
lDictionaryIncrementerOffset = 0


For lDictionaryIncrementer = 0 To oListBoxItemDictionary.Count - 1
    sCurrentString = UCase(oListBoxItemDictionary.Keys(lDictionaryIncrementer))

    If InStr(sCurrentString, sFilterString) Then
        oListBoxItemDictionary(oListBoxItemDictionary.Keys(lDictionaryIncrementer)) = "Show"
    ElseIf sFilterString = vbNullString Then
        oListBoxItemDictionary(oListBoxItemDictionary.Keys(lDictionaryIncrementer)) = "Show"
    Else
        oListBoxItemDictionary(oListBoxItemDictionary.Keys(lDictionaryIncrementer)) = "Hide"
    End If
Next lDictionaryIncrementer

For lListIncrementer = 0 To lLastListItem

    If InvoiceProductAssociation.CatapultItemIdAndDescriptionListBox.Selected(lListIncrementer) = True Then
        oListBoxSelectedDictionary("Selected") = InvoiceProductAssociation.CatapultItemIdAndDescriptionListBox.List(lListIncrementer)
    End If

Next lListIncrementer

InvoiceProductAssociation.CatapultItemIdAndDescriptionListBox.Clear

For lDictionaryIncrementer = 0 To oListBoxItemDictionary.Count - 1

    If oListBoxItemDictionary.Items(lDictionaryIncrementer) = "Show" Then

        With InvoiceProductAssociation.CatapultItemIdAndDescriptionListBox
            .AddItem oListBoxItemDictionary.Keys(lDictionaryIncrementer)
            If oListBoxSelectedDictionary("Selected") = oListBoxItemDictionary.Keys(lDictionaryIncrementer) Then
                InvoiceProductAssociation.CatapultItemIdAndDescriptionListBox.Selected(lDictionaryIncrementer + lDictionaryIncrementerOffset) = True
            End If
        End With
    Else
        lDictionaryIncrementerOffset = lDictionaryIncrementerOffset - 1
    End If

    lListIncrementer = lListIncrementer + 1

Next lDictionaryIncrementer

End Sub
```

The number of items being loaded into the dictionary are over 1,000, but dictionaries have been highly responsive for me in the past, so I'm thinking its the .additem is causing the lag.

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on either how to add the items to the list-box faster, or has a suggestion for successfully only triggering the filter once the user has stopped typing for x seconds.

Comment: Instead of `.additem` paste all items found on the dictionary in a range on a hidden sheet, then use `.RowSource` on the listbox to update all items at once.

Comment: Not familiar with that, I'll look it up and give it a go.  Thanks for the suggestion, Ricardo A

Comment: `.RowSource` requires a range like `Sheet1!A2:A50` and it will show all 50 items without using `.additem`. If your range has empty cells, it will also show empty items on the list. Based on your already written code, instead of marking the lists as "Show" you clear the sheet first `.Cells.ClearContents` and start adding each of those "Show" items on the Sheet. After all are added, you find the last cell `.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and then you set up the `.RowSource` with that range. This will add all items to the list.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo A, that's precisely what I did.  It's actually a bit slower, I have screenupdating off and the worksheet is hidden, but I get a little spinny "I'm thinking" icon every time I type a character into the textbox.

Comment: The point is to reduce the loops to a single loop. The loops are slowing this down. How about adding the dictionary items to an array instead of adding them to a Cell, then paste the array. This way you only paste once on the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Ricardo - that was helpful!  I was able to get it down to one loop, I also then used a collection instead of a dictionary which sped it up.